# passing value from an action method to view from where it is called

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In one view (view1) there is a text box and a button beside it.
i click on that button, i am popping another view (Create view) as a seperate window.
in create view i am entering some values and creating a record in db. out of these
values one value i have to send back to "View1". how can i send this value...?

i am opening view2 from view1 like

```
<input type="button" value="Get ID"
  onclick="window.open('<%=Url.Action("Create","Controller1") %>',
      '','scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=800,resizable=yes');" 
  />
```

View2 contains some fields like Name,Email etc... and I click "Create" to call HTTPPOST. there i add the values to db including a generated guid. i want to send this ID to view1.

Answer (score 1):

If these are not in the same window, there is no direct way.

However, when you popup second window, you can start polling your database using AJAX and when database change is done in the create view, your polling will return the value and update the view.

This is neither an MVC nor an ASP.NET question.

Comment: i am opening view2 from view1 like <input type="button" value="Get ID" onclick="window.open('<%= Url.Action("Create","Controller1") %>', '','scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=800,resizable=yes');" />      View2 contains some fields like Name,Email etc... and I click "Create" to call HTTPPOST. there i add the values to db including a generated guid. i want to send this ID to view1

Comment: Hi Aliostad, Could you please post how it can be done with AJAX

Comment: I cannot explain all about AJAX in here - you need to understand how it works and how to use it. Read this one, it is a good one: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use javascript
In view1

```
...
var popup = window.open("view2");
popup.opener = this
...
window.updateData = function(newValue){
    alert(newValue);
}
```

in view2

```
window.opener.updateData(form.inputname.value);
```

========================================================

UPDATE:

After further information added to the question, I don't think this option would work easily and it will be easier to use Aliostad answer.

Comment: i am opening view2 from view1 like

Comment: <input type="button" value="Get ID" onclick="window.open('<%= Url.Action("Create","Controller1") %>', '','scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=800,resizable=yes');" />

Comment: View2 contains some fields like Name,Email etc... and I click "Create" to call HTTPPOST. there i add the values to db including a generated guid. i want to send this ID to view1.